# How to secure the connection between my android app and the PHP file that communicates with my MySql server?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, security

I wanted to get advice on something I'm doing.

I have an `Android app` where I have activities that I need to show user data.

In an activity I allow the user to modify their data, there are 2 `EditText`, in a `VISIBLE EditText` I insert the new "`Username`" and in another `EditText GONE` I insert the `id` of the user and then send the data to the `PHP` file , which then through a `Query` will modify the data in the `MySql` server.

To authenticate users I use [Facebook Account Kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android).

When users are validated the app receives a `Token` and thanks to that `Token` I can request the `Account Kit` user `ID` which in my case I also saved as a user `ID` in my database.

Is it safe to send the user `ID` from the `App` to the `PHP` file in this way?

What can I do to secure the sending of sensitive data?

I have read that I should use an `HTTPS` connection, but would that be enough?

Or do my `API` also hit something?

If anyone has any advice for me, I'd love to hear from you and learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

What can I do to secure the sending of sensitive data?

For this,

Set header to the URL.

in the header part, you set key-value pair like this

for ex.

```
AuthorizationToken- C8173B34CBD1F2F5
```

Value is nothing but 16 digit constant (Create random constant and use it).

While you are using `POST` method or `GET` method you need to apply this header.

Match value of a header in your PHP code then the only process your request i.e post data to the database or get data from a database.

Comment: Instead of creating random key at app side. Random Key should be generated at server side and pass to the app in Login response so App can use this key in further API's as AuthorizationToken.

Comment: if I used the facebook account kit token to validate API calls? That is if the user is logged in and has the token then I call the method, otherwise I deny the operation. It could go well?

Comment: @SimoneBruziches Are you sure that account kit token remain same everytime ? And how you validate token with server side. Token should be generated at server side which will not be change for particular user.

Comment: But if I use a token of my own, where do I save it? In shared preferrbces it doesn't seem like a safe place, where can I save it?